# C# WinForms MonthCalendar Control - Customizable Date Range?

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

I have a list of dates.
I would like to be able to populate a windows forms monthcalendar control to show these dates as selectable(clickable) dates, whilst any date that is not in the list is disabled on the calendar control.
Is it possible to do this?

regards,

Comment: Why not show a ComboBox with list of available dates instead?

Comment: Because the client wants to see a pretty calendar control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [MinDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.mindate(VS.80).aspx) and [MaxDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.maxdate(VS.80).aspx) properties in order to give the user a specific range of dates to choose from. I don't believe removing dates between MinDate and MaxDate is a function the current control supports. You'd have to implement your own custom MonthCalendar control for that.